# sublime text short-cut to search for html elements/tags whose source file name or location is unknown?

Tags: html, tags, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

Is there a shortcut in Sublime text (like "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>") that searches for html elements/tags in a file whose name or location is **unknown** in a project?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but you can use `Ctrl+R` to search for elements by their ID names.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this only gives elements who have an id!

Comment: Strongly doubt there's a feature like that built into Sublime Text.  There might be a package plugin that does though.